# Running commands as different user from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have 2 users: usr1 and usr2. Neither is a root user.

usr1 starts a bash script. And from the script, I want to run some commands as usr2.
I understand that the way to do it is:

```
su -l <usr2> -c "command"
```

The issue is with passing the password. These are 2 different users with different privileges, so, skipping the password for usr2 is not an option.

This script can go interactive, and ask the user for the password. Is there a way to do this in bash script ?

Comment: Security is of utmost importance, and so NOPASSWD is NOT an option

Comment: When I put `su -l $anotheruser -c whoami` in a bash script and run it, I am prompted for the password, then `whoami` runs as the 2nd user.  Is that not what you require?

Comment: @JigglyNaga this works when I am manually running it, but how can i interact with the user to enter password from a bash script when su asks for password ?

Comment: What else do you mean by "interact with the user to enter a password"?  The script gives control to `su`, which prompts the user directly.  Do you want it to pop up a dialogue box instead?

Comment: @JigglyNaga Thanks. That works, but i think I should've been more precise on my question. In actual, I have like 30-40 commands which needs to run as usr2. That means I have to enter password everytime. I am trying to find a way user enters the usr2 password once, and the script can use it then on.

Comment: You can edit your question to provide the needed precision.

Comment: Can you put all the commands in a single call to su? `su -l u2 -c "sh -c 'cmd1; cmd2; ...'"` -- that may be a quoting mess, but would it work for you? Or perhaps, write the commands to a file, then `su -l u2 c "sh /path/to/commands.file"`

Comment: @glennjackman thanks. I think I will go with the option of putting all the usr2 commands to a different sh file, and then call that from the primary file using su.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your sudoers file setup so that user 1 can sudo to user 2 BUT only run that one command (with no password)? Does that still meet your security concerns?

I think the sudoers would be something like

username hostname = NOPASSWD: /path/to/command

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, that wont meet the security requirement. Ideally, usr2 is a totally different person with no knowledge of usr1 credentials and vice versa.

Comment: @Manoj  If usr1 has no knowledge of usr2's credentials, how/why are they expected to know each other's passwords?

Comment: @JigglyNaga They wont. When the script is run, and when it's time for usr2 commands to run, user-2 has to come and type in the usr2 password.

Comment: I am re-reading all of this, your specific question is that there are several commands and you don't want the user to enter the password over and over. Why don't you put all of the commands one after another in your original script: sudo -l <usr2> -c "command1 ; command2 ; command3"

Comment: @number9 thanks. I think I will go with the option of putting all the usr2 commands to a different sh file, and then call that from the primary file using su